# How derivatives of integrals like $G(x)=\int_{x-\sin x}^{\sin x}\arcsin(t)dt$ are computed?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I need to find the derivative of $G(x)=\int_{x-\sin x}^{\sin x}\arcsin(t)dt$. I know I don't have to find the integral, but I just have troubles computing the derivative. I suppose I get: $\arcsin(\sin x)-\arcsin(x-\sin x)$ which gets me to: $x-\arcsin(x-\sin x)$. However, the answer says:  $\arcsin(\sin x)-\arcsin(x-\sin x)(1-\cos x)$, which again leads me to the main question: what in this algorithm did I miss?

Comment: First write $\int_a^b=\int_a^0+\int_0^b$. Then use the FTOC *and the chain rule*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(t)$ be any primitive of $\arcsin t$. Then:

$$ G(x) = F(\sin x) - F(x-\sin x) $$
and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F'(t)=\arcsin t$, hence:

$$ G'(x) = \cos x\, F'(\sin x) - (1-\cos x) F'(x-\sin x) \\= x \cos x - (1-\cos x)\arcsin(x-\sin x).$$

Answer (score 2):

This is based on fundamental theorem of calculus and the use of chain rule for derivatives. Suppose we are given a function of the form $$F(x) = \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}\phi(t)\,dt$$ then we can take a constant number $k$ and write the integral as $$F(x) = \int_{k}^{h(x)}\phi(t)\,dt - \int_{k}^{g(x)}\phi(t)\,dt = A(x) - B(x)$$ Now let us put $u = h(x), v = g(x)$ so that $$A(x) = \int_{k}^{u}\phi(t)\,dt, \,B(x) = \int_{k}^{v}\phi(t)\,dt$$ From chain rule we get $$\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{dA}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$ and by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we get $$\frac{dA}{du} = \phi(u)$$ Also we have $$\frac{du}{dx} = h'(x)$$ so we finally get $$A'(x) = \frac{dA}{dx} = \phi(u)h'(x) = \phi(h(x))h'(x)$$ Similarly $$B(x) = \phi(g(x))g'(x)$$ and thus $$F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}\phi(t)\,dt\right)= A'(x) - B'(x) = \phi(h(x))h'(x) - \phi(g(x))g'(x)\tag{1}$$ Here we have $$G(x) = \int_{x - \sin x}^{\sin x}\arcsin t\,dt$$ and using formula $(1)$ we get
\begin{align}
G'(x) &= \arcsin(\sin x)\cos x - \arcsin(x - \sin x)(1 - \cos x)\notag\\
&= x\cos x - (1 - \cos x)\arcsin(x - \sin x)\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula for differentiation under the integral sign, which is one of the things people can never remember and always have to look up.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Another option is to use the definition of the derivative and see what you get:

$\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\delta x}(\int^{a(x+\delta x)}_{b(x+\delta x)}f(t)dt-\int^{a(x)}_{b(x)})f(t)dt$

Which can be rewritten as:

$\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\delta x}(\int^{a(x+\delta x)}_{a(x)}f(t)dt-\int^{b(x+\delta x)}_{b(x)})f(t)dt$.

As you take $\delta x\rightarrow 0$, you can take the integrands in both (infinitesimally short) intervals to be constant (substituting $t=a(x)$ or $t=b(x)$ accordingly) and get:

$\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{a(x+\delta x)-a(x)}{\delta x}f(a(x))-\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{b(x+\delta x)-b(x)}{\delta x}f(a(x))=a'(x)f(a(x))-b'(x)f(b(x))$